# Oracle autotask results of space advisor

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, maintenance

When querying the dba_autotask_client view on a Oracle 12c database, I can see that the auto space advisor is enabled. Oracle docs says the findings are now implemented automatically. How can I view the results of this autotask?

```
CLIENT_NAME                      STATUS   CONSUMER_GROUP       MEAN_JOB_DURATION
-------------------------------- -------- -------------------- --------------------------------------------------
sql tuning advisor               ENABLED  ORA$AUTOTASK         +000000000 00:00:00.700000000
auto optimizer stats collection  ENABLED  ORA$AUTOTASK         +000000000 00:00:06.841993315
auto space advisor               ENABLED  ORA$AUTOTASK         +000000000 00:00:01.273776967
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This auto task identifies segments that have space available for reclamation and makes recommendations on how to defragment those segments.

You can use [DBMS_SPACE.ASA_RECOMMENDATIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_space.htm#ARPLS68099) procedure to see the results.

Or you can see the same results in the Oracle Enterprise Manager.

For example:
Go to `Advisor Central` and Select the `Advisory Type` as shown in the following screenshot(OEM 11g).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also a dba view showing the space advisor recommendation: [DBA_ADVISOR_RECOMMENDATIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_3026.htm#REFRN23323)